# If $3^x = 5$, $5^y = 10$, $10^z = 16$, then what is $3^{xyz}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Can't post images so I'll type it here:

$$3^x = 5,\qquad 5^y = 10,\qquad 10^z = 16$$

Then what is $3^{xyz}$?

I've spent like an hour trying to solve it and I failed. Help would be super duper appreciated.
Thank you!

Edit: uhh I think I solved it? Would the answer be $16$?

Basically I put $3^x$ in place of the $5$ in $5^y = 10$, so now I have $(3^x)^y = 10$ (which is $3^{xy} = 10$), did the same for the last equation and I got $16$ as an answer, but can anyone confirm this?

Comment: To be clear: Do you intend $xyz$ to be the exponent on $3$?

Comment: Can you give a better title? That's what everyone is doing.

Comment: Hint $(p^n)^m=p^{nm}$

Comment: Yes the exponent on 3, and I'm sorry this is my first time here :D ALSO YES RANDOMGIRL I think I just solved it using that

Comment: **Hint** $\large\ 3^{\large xyz} = ((3^{\large x})^{\large y})^{\large z}\ \ $

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$3^{xyz}$ is the same as $(3^x)^{yz}$ and $3^x=5$

this becomes $5^{yz}$ and this is the same as $(5^y)^{z}$ and if $5^y=10$

this becomes $10^z$ and since $10^z=16$ you have that $3^{xyz}=16$

Comment: That's indeed the solution, I just did not expect it to be this short of an answer. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, could you verify this as your chosen answer please, Thanks

Comment: Took me a while to figure out how lmao, but I gotcha. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Ricky gives the best solution but here is a brute force solution that uses more machinery. We note that
$$
x=\frac{\log 5}{\log 3};\quad y=\frac{\log 10}{\log 5}; \quad z=\frac{\log 16}{\log 10}
$$ 
so
$$
xyz=\frac{\log 16}{\log 3}=\log_{3}16
$$
whence
$$
3^{xyz}=16.
$$

Comment: That was an interesting read, thanks! I'm still not too experienced in logarithms